# React-native Modal component animation

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to make Modal appear from left to right?

Right now I have this and its only sliding from bottom to top:

```
 <Modal animationType={'slide'} visible={showModal}>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowModal(false)}>
        <Feather name="menu" size={40} color="red" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </Modal>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `npm i react-native-modal` to get your desired result.

```
<Modal
      animationIn="slideInLeft"
      animationOut="slideOutRight"
      animationInTiming={500}
      animationOutTiming={750}
      isVisible={showModal}
      useNativeDriver={true}
      onBackButtonPress={() => {
          setShowModal(!showModal);
      }}>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowModal(false)}>
        <Feather name="menu" size={40} color="red" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
 </Modal>
```